# how to stop storing empty paths to database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
while(file_exists($desktop_filename_1280x800 = strtolower($desktop_dir_1280x800 . 'wall_desktop_1280x800_' .
$_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['name'])));
```

above code generates a path similar to this: `../../images/desktop_walls/1280x800/wall_desktop_1280x800_`

```
INSERT INTO walls(d_1280x800_path) VALUES ($desktop_filename_1280x800);
```

and the query above stores it to the database.

What I would like to do is stop it from storing to the database since it is an empty path. I just want to store the path that contains .jpg .png at the end.

Comment: So validate your string before saving it. What's your question?

Comment: that is the question I think..how to validate it?

Comment: It seems from your question that you just need to put a check on empty string before inserting as you have asked how to stop inserting empty paths.

Comment: yes..exactly..tried searching google, I think I'm searching it efficiently..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the value is not empty. Not empty, insert it.

```
while(file_exists($desktop_filename_1280x800 = strtolower($desktop_dir_1280x800 . 'wall_desktop_1280x800_' .
$_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['name'])));

if (!empty(trim($desktop_filename_1280x800))) {
  INSERT INTO walls(d_1280x800_path) VALUES ($desktop_filename_1280x800);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before your routine you should check if there was an error:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['error']
```

A value of 4 indicates that the file was NOT uploaded.

For more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php